# Fields not visible after groupby?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework-6

What I have now:

```
var batch_pymnts2 = (from a in ctx.WarehouseStatementBatchPayments
                     join b in ctx.WarehouseStatementBatches on a.WarehouseStatementBatchID equals b.ID
                     join c in ctx.WarehousePaymentInvoices on a.ID equals c.WarehouseStatementBatchPaymentID
                     where b.ID == batchID
                     select new
                     { 
                         PaymentId = a.ID, 
                         PaymentNet = a.Net, 
                         PaymentType = a.Type 
                     })
                     .GroupBy(d => d.PaymentId).Where(x => x.Count() == 1);
```

I need to query these results like so:

```
var test = (from a in batch_pymnts2 where a.PaymentNet > 100 select a).ToList();
```

However, I cant see the fields of the (anonymous) type that the first statement uses to project the results into.

Will I need to use a defined type in the query for the projection?  Is there a way to do it with anonymous types?

**[update]**
I managed to change the source query a bit, moving the group by inside and before the group by.  This lets the fields of the anonymous type being projected, be "exposed" in further statements.

```
            var count2 =  (from a in WarehouseStatementBatchPayments
                                                 join b in WarehouseStatementBatches on a.WarehouseStatementBatchID equals b.ID
                                                 join c in WarehousePaymentInvoices on a.ID equals c.WarehouseStatementBatchPaymentID
                                                 group a by a.ID into grp
                                                 from d in grp
                                                 where d.WarehouseStatementBatchID == batchID && grp.Count() == 1
                                                 select new { PaymentId = d.ID, PaymentNet = d.Net, PaymentType = d.Type }).ToList();
```

Comment: You group by `PaymentId`, why would you expect to see any other fields?

Comment: I want a list of some of the values from WarehouseStatementBatchPayment but only those where WarehouseStatementBatchPayment.ID is in in WarehouseStatementBatchInvoices ONCE

Comment: @bitshift That doesn't address his question, and it doesn't explain why you were trying to query by PaymentNet in your question.

Comment: @bitshift "This lets the fields of the anonymous type being projected, be "exposed" in further statements."? What does "exposed" mean? Were they hidden somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

`batch_pymnts2` is a sequence of group objects. In effect, it is a collection of collections of your anonymous type. Each item in `batch_pymnts2` has this:

```
group.Key; /* a PaymentId value */

((IEnumerable)group); /* the anon type items grouped together in this group */
```

[Those group objects implement the `IGrouping` interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344977(v=vs.110).aspx). Their `Key` property is the `PaymentId` values that define the groups. If you enumerate the groups (they implement `IEnumerable<T>`), you'll get the anonymous objects that you grouped by `PaymentId`:

```
var test = batch_pymnts2.SelectMany(g => g.Where(anon => anon.PaymentNet > 100));
```

`test` is now an enumeration of your anonymous type, because we have now enumerated a subset of the anon items from each of the groups, and (in effect) unioned all those little enumerations of anon back into one big one.

If you want to select groups which have at least one anonymous thingy with PaymentNet > 100, try this:

```
//  Groups which have at least one PaymentNet > 100
var t2 = batch_pymnts2.Where(g => g.Any(anon => anon.PaymentNet > 100));

//  PaymentIds of the groups which have at least one PaymentNet > 100
var ids = t2.Select(g => g.Key);

//  PaymentIds that appear only once
var singles = t2.Where(g => g.Count == 1).Select(g => g.Key);
```

I don't know why you're grouping them, or what your `PaymentNet > 100` query is meant to accomplish, so I'm not sure exactly how to write the query you want. But your starting point is that you're querying a sequence of `group` objects which contain enumerations of your anonymous type -- not a sequence of that type itself.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  See my update the original post.